# Managing online users on server without using websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to show a list of connected users without using Websockets.
I thought to use http header

*Connection:keep-alive*

to get persistent connections.
Then, when clients leave the website, they would run a listener handler on *beforeunload* event in order to notice server that a client is going to leave the list.
But, how is server able to notify the rest of connected clients to update their lists? (remember, without using websockets, and if possible, without making clients asking any interval to server)

Comment: I didn't realize that this problem is called "pushing data to clients". I got some info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106198/pushing-data-to-a-client and https://blog.stanko.io/do-you-really-need-websockets-343aed40aa9b

Comment: Yeah web sockets would be the way to go for push events. They are way cool. I would suggest looking into something like socket.io to take make it a bit easier to setup. But web apps before websockets were introduce would either do http long-polling or just request for data every x amount of time elapsed.

Comment: Also make sure to mark my response as an answer if it satisfied your original question.

Comment: What's the issue with web sockets?  Ideally you'd use Server-Sent Events, but you should explain *why* you don't want to use Web Sockets.

Comment: @Brad Due to clients don't need to send data to server but client's just need to receive data of server, or in other words, server notifies to clients by pushing data to them at any time, one of the solutions you can achieve it is using SSE (Server-sent events) for example, as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using the `Connection: keep-alive` header means that the browser and server will carry out multiple http requests/responses over one tcp connection vs opening and closing a tcp connection for each http request. But this still doesn't allow the server to just push data whenever. *For the server to respond with anything, the client still would need to make requests*. So it isn't really related to real time push events.

> and if possible, without making clients asking any interval to server

This isn't really possible. Like I said, a server cannot send data to a client over http unless the client first requested it.

So you either have to make interval requests for the user list

**or**

you can make it "simulate" pushing from the server with http long-polling.

The basic idea is that the server never "finishes" its response to a client request, but sends its response in chunks, when really those chunks would be treated on the client side as separate pieces of data. But this solution is hacky and has a lot of cons. Either way, http long-polling would more or less simulate pushing data real time.